Porque no me corre el api de cuty.io en mi acortador

async function obtenerLink(url, link, enableObtenerLink_1, index){
    const response = await fetch('https://cuty.io/api?api=4bf2745de7c06fe01e8e500b2bf60ee2fe3dbfa9&url=' + url, {
        method: 'GET',
    })
    const retorno = await response.json();
    retorno.url = url;
    retorno.link = link;
    retorno.enableObtenerLink_1 = enableObtenerLink_1;
    retorno.index= index;
    return retorno;
}


Porque tiene problema de CORS, es decir desde el navegador no podrás consumir aquella API, solo desde algún programa de servidor podrás hacerlo.
La solución es obtener un token y usar la API Rápida, la cual tiene el siguiente formato:
https://api.cuty.io/quick?token={token}&url={url}
Ejemplo:


fetch("https://api.cuty.io/quick?token=87c7e60190fc2909020a01d61&url=https://es.stackoverflow.com/").then(a=>a.json()).then(console.log);




como iria exactamente en el codigo me podrias ayudar,

@DaniReveliere Primero tienes que obtener una cuenta e ir a https://cuty.io/tools/quick-api para obtener tu token. Luego para utilizarla es igual al código que tú tienes, pero cambia la URL a la que puse en mi respuesta

si tengo mi cuenta pero la verdad que sigue sin generar
